# Google static maps API page mentions that static maps to be used only in browser

Tags: google-maps

In the Google static maps API description (http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/), I found the following statement : (present in the "Overview" section)

"***Note that static maps may only be displayed within browser content; use of static maps outside of the browser is not allowed.***"

I need some help in deciphering the above statement.

Does this mean that the Google static maps has to be used inside a browser and cannot be used in context of a application doing http requests?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting question.

[This section from the "Google Maps API Family" FAQ](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/faq.html#tos_nonweb) says:

> **Can I use Google Maps in my non-Web application?**
>
> Yes, the Google Maps APIs can now be used in Desktop applications, provided that they adhere to the other restrictions of the Terms of Service. Note that in order for a desktop application to be deemed "publicly accessible", there must be a publicly accessible webpage from which it can be downloaded. [See Section 7.1c](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/terms.html#section_7_1) of the Terms of Service for more information.

[The FAQ also explicitly includes the Static Maps API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/faq.html#whatis) as part of the set of "Google Maps APIs" mentioned above:

> **What are the Google Maps APIs?**
>
> The Google Maps APIs give developers several ways of embedding Google Maps into web pages, and allows for either simple use or extensive customization. There are now several API offerings: Google Maps Javascript API, Google Maps API for Flash, Google Static Maps API. In addition, we also offer the Mapplets API to enable the creation of mini-applications that run inside Google Maps. Depending on your needs, you may find yourself using one or a combination of these APIs.

The problem is that [Section 10.8 of the Terms of Use](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/terms.html#section_10_8) is still saying:

> 10 - Except as explicitly permitted in Section 7 or the Maps APIs Documentation, you must not (nor may you permit anyone else to):
>
> ...
>
> 10.8 - use the Static Maps API other than in an implementation in a web browser;

It seems that using the Static Maps in a non-Web application is explicitly permitted in the Maps APIs Documentation, but I wonder if Section 10.8 takes precedence.

I will try to seek further information about this issue, and will update this answer accordingly.

---

Related links:

- [Google Maps API Group: J2SE Desktop App Options](http://groups.google.com/group/google-maps-api/browse_thread/thread/770f34976b16e780)
- [Google Maps API Group: Static Maps and Mobile Applications](http://groups.google.com/group/google-maps-api/browse_thread/thread/e457beb5424ea05b/)